# text box positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, linguistics, expex

I need to put three text boxes in the example below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{expex}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\Tikzmark[2]{%
\tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};}

\NewDocumentCommand\DrawArrow{O{}mmmmO{3}}{
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[-,line width=0.5pt,shorten >= 2pt,shorten <= 2pt,#1] 
 (#2) -- ++(0,-#6\ht\strutbox) coordinate (aux) -- node[#4] {#5} (#3|-      aux) -- (#3);}

\begin{document}

\pex \rightcomment{Engl}
\a\Tikzmark{enda}{H}e {} {} {} {} {} {} {} br\Tikzmark{starta} {o}\Tikzmark{endb}{k}e {} {} {} {} {} t\Tikzmark{startb}{h}e c\Tikzmark{endc}{a}r {} {} {} {} {} {} \textsc{ye\Tikzmark{startc}{s}terday} ]
\DrawArrow{starta}{enda}{midway, fill=white}{\scshape x}
\DrawArrow{startb}{endb}{midway, fill=white}{\scshape y} 
\DrawArrow{startc}{endc}{midway, fill=white}{\scshape z}
\\
\\
\a \DrawArrow{startc}{enda}{midway, fill=white}{\scshape w}[6]
\xe

\end{document}
```

[image]

These three boxes need to be right below Y, Z, W. Could someone please suggest me how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is up to you to make sure the underbox content fits within the space, as it does not modify the positioning of the underlying graph.

I introduce `\uderbox{<label>}{<under text>}`, which you can customize to suit.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{expex}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}

\newcommand\Tikzmark[2]{%
\tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};}

\NewDocumentCommand\DrawArrow{O{}mmmmO{3}}{
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[-,line width=0.5pt,shorten >= 2pt,shorten <= 2pt,#1] 
 (#2) -- ++(0,-#6\ht\strutbox) coordinate (aux) -- node[#4] {#5} (#3|-      aux) -- (#3);}

\newcommand\underbox[2]{\vphantom{#1}\smash{\stackunder[5pt]{\scshape #1}{%
  \fboxsep=1pt\scriptsize\fbox{#2}}}}

\begin{document}

\pex \rightcomment{Engl}
\a\Tikzmark{enda}{H}e {} {} {} {} {} {} {} br\Tikzmark{starta} {o}\Tikzmark{endb}{k}e {} {} {} {} {} t\Tikzmark{startb}{h}e c\Tikzmark{endc}{a}r {} {} {} {} {} {} \textsc{ye\Tikzmark{startc}{s}terday} ]
\DrawArrow{starta}{enda}{midway, fill=white}{\scshape x}
\DrawArrow{startb}{endb}{midway, fill=white}{\underbox{\scshape y}{Hi, Mom}} 
\DrawArrow{startc}{endc}{midway, fill=white}{\underbox{\scshape z}{!!@\#}}
\\
\\
\a \DrawArrow{startc}{enda}{midway, fill=white}{\underbox{\scshape w}{And now, for something completely different.}}[6]
\xe

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! How can I remove the borders?